# How Azure Event Hubs uses Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

This question is not about the difference between Azure Event Hubs and Azure Service Bus.

The question is as follows:

If you add add Azure Events Hub to your application, then you will notice that it depends on Azure Service Bus, So Events Hub uses and relies on Service Bus. So the question will arise how Events Hub benefit from Service Bus, and how Service Bus fits in the partitioning concept of Events Hub? Does EH creates SB factories under the hood and uses them as partitions? Or what is the story.

I am happy to read articles or books about the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Hubs doesn't use Service Bus but they share common components that is why you may see "Service Bus" references when working with Event Hubs resources like exceptions, metrics, client errors etc.

Comment: Perhaps the question is about EventProcessorHost, How is service bus is helping here? 
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost/5.0.0/